# Change text line in a file by using Matlab

Tags: matlab, dxf

So I have to modify a .dxf file (an Autocad file) by changing some data in it for another one we choose previously. Changing some lines of a .txt file in Matlab is not pretty difficult.

However, I cannot change a specific line when the new input's length is larger than the old one.

This is what I have and I want to change only 1D57:

```
TEXT
 5
1D57
330
1D52
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
```

If I have as an input BBBB, everything goes right since both strings have the same length. The same does not apply when I try with BBBBbbbbbbbbbb:

```
TEXT
5
BBBBbbbbbbbbbb2
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
```

It deletes everything after it until the string stops. It happens the same when the input is shorter: it does not change the line for the new string but it writes until the new input stops. For example, in our case with AAA as an input, the result would be AAA7.

This is basically the code I am using to modify the file:

```
fID = fopen('copia.dxf','r+');
for i = 1:2
    LineToReplace = TextIndex(i);    
    for k = 1:((LineToReplace) - 1);
       fgetl(fID);
    end
    fseek(fID, 0, 'cof');

    fprintf (fID, [Data{i}, '\n']);
end
fclose(fID);
```

Comment: You are just overwriting the data at a particular part of the file, if it's not the same length then it will overwrite past the original field you are trying to modify. To insert data of a different length you would need to create a new file, copy everything up to the point you want to change, insert your new data, then copy everything past the data you want to change.

Answer (score 2):

You need to overwrite at least the rest of the file in order to change it (unless exact number of characters is replaced), as explained in jodag's comment. For instance,

```
  % String to change and it's replacement
  % (can readily be automated for more replacements)
  str_old = '1D52';
  str_new = 'BBBBbbbbbbbbbb';

  % Open input and output files
  fIN = fopen('copia.dxf','r');
  fOUT = fopen('copia_new.dxf','w');

  % Temporary line
  tline = fgets(fIN);

  % Read the entire file line by line
  % Write it to the new file 
  % Replace str_old with str_new when encountered - note, if there is more 
  % than one occurence of str_old in the file all will be replaced - this can
  % be handled with a proper flag
  while (ischar(tline))
      % char(10) is MATLAB's newline character representation
      if strcmp(tline, [str_old, char(10)])
          fprintf(fOUT, '%s \n', str_new);
      else
          % No need for \n - it's already there as we're using fgets
          fprintf(fOUT, '%s', tline);
      end
      tline = fgets(fIN);
  end

 % Close the files
 fclose(fIN);
 fclose(fOUT);

 % Copy the new file into the original
 movefile 'copia_new.dxf' 'copia.dxf'
```

In practice, it is often far easier to simply overwrite the whole file.

As written in the notes - this can be automated for more replacements and it would also need an additional flag to only replace a given string once.

Comment: And then copy the new output file over the original?  So that in the end we have the same filename but with changed content.  (The question asks to change a file, not create a new one.)

Comment: You mean to add those copying lines to the code? Like we discussed?

Comment: Well, yes.  The code you posted ends up generating a _new_ file, while the original is unchanged.  The question asks how to _change_ a file.  So a part of the answer should also be to finally overwrite the original with the new file (copy the new file into the original, like `mv new original`).

Comment: Or rewind the pointers and overwrite the old with the new the same way. I'll propose mv.

Comment: Right.  The first way has the advantage of retaining the inode number.  The second is just simpler.

Comment: (In fact, for "the first way" you'd have to open the file again, for writing. Or, to open it read-write to start with and then you can seek, but that can be error prone)